# Изменение размера вектора векторов занимает много времени при первом запуске ОС

Tags: c++, linux, память, vector

Для представления последовательности изображений я использую вектор объектов своего класса, одним из атрибутов которых является другой вектор. По сути - вектор векторов.
При первом запуске программы изменение размерности каждого элемента вектора (изменение количества пикселей в каждом изображении) занимает много времени. Для буфера на 2000 изображений разрешения 1440х1080 это может занимать 15 секунд.
Однако, при последующих запусках программы времени на это уходит гораздо меньше и так будет вплоть до перезапуска ОС.
Использую Ubuntu 20.04, пробовал изменение размера через resize, застолбить память через reserve и добавлять элементы через emplace_back, ничего не помогло.

```cpp
void MVLImageBuffer::ResizeAllElement(int new_size)
{
    pImageBuff.resize(1);
    (pImageBuff[0]).ImageResize(new_size);
    pImageBuff.reserve(size);
    int p = pImageBuff.capacity();
    //pImageBuff.resize(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
    {
        pImageBuff.emplace_back(pImageBuff[0]);
        //(pImageBuff[i+1]).ImageResize(new_size);
    }
}
```

Изначально был обычный resize, но проблема была той же.
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код, который вызывает проблему. Сколько долго? Сколько коротко? Это миллисекунды или часы?